# Android Gradle - Cache being locked

Tags: android, gradle, build

I am really confused as to why this file is being locked.

It is only locking on a specific project, other projects are fine, so maybe it is to do with my build files, however they have been working fine up until now.

```
"Error:Timeout waiting to lock cp_proj class cache for build file 'D:\Users\RU112828\Development\NavX Fuel - Trunk\Fuel-TestApp\test\build.gradle' (D:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\2.8\scripts\build_64jc2uvb9pu0rruzfn4eaqpd1\cp_proj). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
Owner PID: unknown
Our PID: 7444
Owner Operation: unknown
Our operation: Initialize cache
Lock file: D:\Users\RU112828\.gradle\caches\2.8\scripts\build_64jc2uvb9pu0rruzfn4eaqpd1\cp_proj\cache.properties.lock"
```

There is only one build going on, no simultaneous builds. After a lot of fiddling yesterday i managed to clear the cache and it came back to life. But today this is not the case any more, after clearing the cache it still blocks.

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    androidTestCompile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'robotium-solo-5.5.3.jar')
    //    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile files('libs/robotium-solo-5.5.3.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-15'
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
    android {
        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 15
        }

        lintOptions {
            abortOnError false
        }
        sourceSets
                {
                    androidTest
                            {
                                res.srcDirs = ['res']
                                assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
                            }
                }
    }

}

task assembleDebug(overwrite: true) {}

task copyTask(type: Copy) {
    from 'D:/Users/RU112828/Development/app/myapp.apk'
    into 'build/outputs/apk/'
    rename {
        'test-debug.apk'
    }

    exec { //TODO this is commented out when we do not need a fresh install, when running start up tests then we should un-comment this
        //Force app to uninstall before then being installed.
        commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'adb', 'uninstall', 'com.my.package'

    }
}

assembleDebug.dependsOn copyTask
```

That build script was generated by Robotium Recorder, then i have added the tweak to force uninstall of the app during the assembleDebug phase.

Can anyone please point me towards some insight into why this file is being locked.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I met this problem in my mac, I just force to close studio and reopen it, then everything is ok

Comment: I already tried more time even try with restart but it not working F9, iS there any other solution ...

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal and kill the process that you know, normally all process are know
kill -9 [id]